# Bootstrap tooltip within scrollable content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two containers, as displayed in this [FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/lav911/j8L3A/1/)

Both have content that can become quite lengthy, thus I need to use `overflow: auto` on both containers.

**The HTML structure:**

```
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="left-container" class="go-left overflow-y-auto">
        <div id="left-inner-container">Contents</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right-container" class="go-right overflow-y-auto">
        <div id="right-inner-container">
            <div id="button-wrapper">
                <button type="button" id="tip_button" class="btn primary customized-button">tip</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a button within the `#right-container` that creates a tooltip on click, displayed right next to it. The problem is that, when I have lengthy content (that determines scroll bar to appear), the tooltip won't be placed near the button (on scroll). It will remain relative to the `#maincontainer`. If I make it relative to the `#right-container` the tooltip will be 'chopped' (due to `overflow`).

What I'm seeking is to have the tooltip aligned next to the button when the user scrolls down that area.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap tooltip then add class `'bootstrap-demo'` to parent div of button & make sure you are NOT passing `container:'body'` parameter when initializing tooltip.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your answer (the part related to the 'bootstrap-demo'). Could you perhaps edit my fiddle?

Comment: @Zubzob changed your jsfiddle. Check it. Few other cchanges were required. Such as adding positio:relative to 'button-wrapper' & placement is changed to 'top' in jquery.

Comment: Yes but in my question I specified that I'd like it right next to it (horizontally next). To be more specific, the 'placement' should remain as it was in my fiddle (left). Also I think you need to fork or update the fiddle and paste the new link if you want to demonstrate it.

Comment: Yes But if you are placing it on right then is will get cut due to your right-container's overflow setting. Here is link for edited jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j8L3A/9/.  If you want to stick to your older version then you have to hide tooltip on scroll.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, if you don't set container, the tooltip will be clipped